# Mail account authentication with Oauth2

Tags: civimail

Exchange Online is retiring basic authentication which means, I think, that CiviMail will no longer be able to process bounced messages in Exchange Online mailboxes.  Are there any plans for CiviMail Mail Accounts to use Oauth2 for authenticating with the mail server?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: It's available now for **INBOUND** emails (bounce processing/email processor) in 5.32 as a hidden extension. See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/oauth/#enable-the-module

---

It's in progress for google and would likely be the same for outlook/exchange.

See https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/mail/issues/59

It supports using a bearer token already
but we could use some coding help though for someone to write the code to get/store/use the refresh tokens in order to get the bearer token.